# What can I access with vue2 beforeCreate?

Tags: vuejs2

I'd like to access props or `<tag data-att="info I need">`, but that doesn't seem possible in beforeCreate.  So, what do I have access to in beforeCreate?

Answer (score 1):

`beforeCreate()` is called synchronously immediately after the instance has been initialized, before data observation and event/watcher setup. (See docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeCreate)

You can only access the component's `props` and `this.$options` (the options object you defined for this component)

Comment: I can't seem to get at the props. this.directly or this.$props.indirectly.  Although this may be because I'm making tags with vue-custom-element

Comment: @TarekAdam is your question answered so far?